# Voting problems in app

Tags: bug, android-app

When you vote on a post in the app (all sites), it remembers the vote on the server, but shortly after voting, the vote will appear to be unrecorded on the device until you refresh the page. If you try to vote again on the post, it gives you an error that `You've already voted on this post`, however it doesn't show the vote. (Until the page is refreshed)

- App Version: 1.0.85
- Device Manufacturer: motorola
- Device Model: MotoE2(4G-LTE)

  - OS Version: 5.1 (2)

Comment: Probably dupe, unless the asker didn't actually confirm that the bug can be triggered even without scrolling (which seems to be the focus of the dupe target source), in which case this specific question has a bigger scope than the other. Cullub, have you  got any other info about the error and how to reproduce it?

Comment: No, actually I guess this is a duplicate - I didn't see that.